# Mapping the return type of subscribe to other type

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java3

Map the return type in RXJava

```
@Queue(ProductTopicConstants.DELETE_PRODUCT)
    public Single<String> Delete(String id) {
        LOG.info(String.format("Listener --> Delete the document from the database"));
        ProductSearchCriteria criteria = new ProductSearchCriteria();
        criteria.setId(id);
        Bson query = QueryBuilder.QueryBuilder(criteria, Bson.class).get(0);
        return  Single.fromPublisher(
                this.repository.getCollection(ProductConstrants.PRODUCT_COLLECTION_NAME, Product.class)
                        .deleteOne(query)).flatMap(item ->{
                            if(item.getDeletedCount() == 0)
                                return Single.just("Success");
                            else
                                return Single.just(id);
        });
    }
```

Now return type is **Disposable** type, is it possible to convert to other Type such as `Single<String>` I tried `flatMap` and `MAP`, but when I subscribe the method it is again converted to the **Disposable**

Comment: Remove the `subscribe()`? If you don't want to subscribe from the observable yet, then don't.

Comment: @Progman I need to subscribe otherwise this.repository.getCollection(ProductConstrants.PRODUCT_COLLECTION_NAME, Product.class)
                        .deleteOne(query) will not execute, need to subscribe to it

Comment: Do you want to create a so called "hot observable"? Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of where the values are produced/generated, where/how you want to consume them and what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @Progman I am trying to convert to Single<String> and return the value

Comment: When you remove the `subscribe()` call, then you get that exact return type, since that is the return type defined of the `Single.fromPublisher()` method. Explain why it doesn't work that you remove the `subscribe()` call and explain what you want instead.

Comment: @Progman Since I am using rabbitMQ with Micronaut framework, from the producer when I call the listener method, the execution doesn't happen, however, I need to call the subscribe method explicitly to execute the delete operation. from the Micronaut documentation, it is not a good practice to return the reactive type from the listener method, so I need to execute the subscribe method  "RPC consumer methods must never return a reactive type. Because the resulting publish needs to occur on the same thread and only a single item can be emitted, there is no value in doing so."

Comment: Is using `first()` or `firstElement()` (depending on what you need) an option? Please edit your question with a more detailed description of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Progman There is no first() or firstElement() function available. Updated the code the above code won't execute unless it is subscribe to it.

Comment: Check http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Observable.html#first-T- and http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Observable.html#firstElement-- for the documentation for `Observable.first()` and `Observable.firstElement()`.

Comment: @Progman I can use .blockingGet() , but I don't want to block the thread

Comment: I don't understand what you try to achieve here as there seems to be a conceptual mismatch in your responses. `Single<String>` implies you setup the delete action and something else will do the subscribing, thus the setup can run asynchronously. Also you mentioned `blockingGet` which will block to get you a result. Also `Single.just(null)` will fail with `NullPointerException`.